# Map a set of strings to another set of strings, optimise similarity

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, string-metrics, string-matching

Suppose we have a similarity measure `s : String x String -> [0, 1]` and sets `K`, `L` in `String` with `|K| <= |L|`. The task is to find an injection `f : S -> T` such that `Sum({s(k, f(k)) | k in K})` is maximised. That is, f should be an injection which maximises similarity.

My naive approach would be to compute all the similarities `s(k, l)` at once, then use a polynomial time bipartite graph matching algorithm such as the Hungarian algorithm or Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to compute an optimal matching. Here, I would have `s` be the n-gram similarity function from Kondrak's "N
-gram similarity and distance" paper.

Does anyone know of a cheaper way to go about this? I'm hoping for something which considers the whole sets, rather than pairwise similarity alone.

Comment: You haven't stated any restrictions on the similarity measure `s`, so any faster-than-HA-and-FF algorithm that you could find to solve this problem would in essence *be* a faster-than-HA-and-FF algorithm *for bipartite matching*.  In detail: *any* bipartite graph could be converted to an instance of your problem by mapping all vertices to distinct dummy strings, and specifying `s` as an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with rows and columns each indexed by these strings.  I don't know of lower bounds for bipartite matching, so such an algorithm might conceivably exist, but it would be a major result in CS.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the answer and sorry for taking so long to reply. I was wondering whether it was possible to take a different approach, rather than simply computing all similarities and then using an existing bipartite graph matching algorithm.

I thought there might be some solution which involves growing a matching over approximated (more cheaply computed) similarities,  improving the matching and similarity approximations over time. Maybe an adapted HA. I know there might not be a definitive answer to this, but suggestions in the right direction would be appreciated.